# Text overflow on Careers if the company name is an URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If the company name is an URL (or is a very long word), you can see some overflow on the right box:

[image: Overflow screen example]

Nothing dramatic, but hey, it's a CSS bug anyway :p

Comment: They shouldn't use the company name to provide an URL...

Comment: @Bakuriu, Perhaps, but the buggy look is on our site, not theirs.

Comment: @JNF I don't get your comment. I wanted to simply remark the dumbness of companies using the name field to place an url. Sure there are probably some companies with a real name that overflows, yet I don't think we should fix everything caused by a dumb user misusing the fields. So the dailymotion page isn't a good example of thing SO should fix (or better: the fix is just changing `http://www.dailymotion.com` to the correct `dailymotion` and ping them saying "learn to read field names when building your company page").

Comment: @Bakuriu Dailymotion has not been smart here, but it is weird that the company name is correct below (*Plus d'annonces chez Dailymotion* which is something like *More jobs at Dailymotion* in English)... Does a company has to put again their global information for each offer?

Comment: @Bakuriu, SO should take care of SO. It can be by hiding overflow, by recognizing and reformatting, or by blocking out companies with long names. Whatever companies do, SO should always look great.

Comment: BTW, there are companies (*eg. websites*) who have a url for a name

Comment: For example, "comparethemarket.com".  That may not be the registered name of the company, but it is certainly the trading name, and is the right text to put in the "company name" field.  I suspect SO is having trouble with very long names _without_ spaces.

Comment: I did notice the same with Booking.com a few days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This issue has been fixed.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/82100/senior-back-end-developer-relevant-content-team-dailymotion)

Part of the problem was that the company "name" in this particular example was a full web address. We corrected this by changing their name to their correct name, but then we also put in place some CSS to properly trap for this in the future:

```
h1.-title { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Answer (score 8):

While others argue who to blame in the comments:

http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/all.min.css?v=39334235357a

```
.link, a {
    color: #0095ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* break-word does the job */
}
```

`Break-word` fixes the problem for us, the remaining problem is for DailyMotion to deal with, looks bad wrapped like that. We wouldn't like to troll them though, right?